# How to Replace &#13; In Text?

Tags: php, xml

XML:

```
<programme start="20180124160000 +0200" stop="20180124164500 +0200" channel="506"><title lang="he">&#13;
         ריזולי ואיילס 7 11. הגופה</title><desc lang="he">&#13;
         מתח. 11. הגופה: גופתו של קברן נמצאת בתוך ארון קבורה של אחד מלקוחותיו והדבר מוביל את חברי הצוות לחשיפת גופות נוספות. ג'יין מבשרת לקרוביה על החלטתה לעבור לאף.בי.איי.</desc></programme></programmes>
```

I want to remove from the text all the `&#13;`

How to remove it with str_replace?

PHP:

```
$c = $xpath->query("div[@class = 'show']/text()", $container)->item(0);
$desc = $c->nodeValue;}
$desc = str_replace("&#13;", "", $desc);
$echo desc;
```

Comment: Try `echo str_replace("&#13;", "", $name);`

Comment: that is most likely a hidden unicode `\r` (linefeed) character. Where and how is that coming from?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner It comes from my xml file, the code is actually longer in principle. I'll update the post in a minute

Comment: this seems Windows related or the file is coming from a windows based file. Is this uploaded from a user? that is a hidden linefeed character, that I know.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I updated the post

Answer (score 1):

The parser will do it for you:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml('<foo>&#13;</foo>');
var_dump($document->documentElement->textContent);
```

Output:

```
string(1) "
"
```

The var_dump() output shows that the string contains only a single character - a carriage return. However the parser will do this only for normal text nodes, not for CDATA sections:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml('<foo><![CDATA[&#13;]]></foo>');
var_dump($document->documentElement->textContent);
```

Output:

```
string(5) "&#13;"
```

In this you need to use string functions to replace the entity manually.

Tip: With `DOMXpath::evaluate()` you can fetch the text content directly as a string by using the `string` function to cast the node list:

```
$description = $xpath->evaluate("string(div[@class = 'show'])", $container);
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

It seems that somewhere along the line, the string has been html-encoded.

You can decode it again using:

```
html_entity_decode('thisisa&#13;test')
```

or:

```
html_entity_decode($your_encoded_string)
```

[See here](https://3v4l.org/Ps3kl) how it works.

Comment: It works for me in the view of the browser, but the content saved in XML still shows these &#13; , I paste the full php code?

Comment: @dizzy The code you have shown only gets data from the xml. If the problem is with the generation of the xml, you should post the code that generates the xml instead.

Comment: I dont know how to get the link from 3v4l so i paste in ghostbin: https://ghostbin.com/paste/33o4a